# Kubernetes Pod Status: "PodFailed" due to "EvictionByEvictionAPI". How to diagnose and resolve?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I'm running Airflow through Kubernetes and I'm observing a Kubernetes pod that has failed (Every time I retry), and upon inspecting the pod's status, I found the following conditions:

```
 'status': {'conditions': [{'last_probe_time': None,
                        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 27, 16, 49, 31, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                        'message': 'Eviction API: evicting',
                        'reason': 'EvictionByEvictionAPI',
                        'status': 'True',
                        'type': 'DisruptionTarget'},
                       {'last_probe_time': None,
                        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 27, 16, 8, 27, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                        'message': None,
                        'reason': None,
                        'status': 'True',
                        'type': 'Initialized'},
                       {'last_probe_time': None,
                        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 27, 16, 50, 1, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                        'message': None,
                        'reason': 'PodFailed',
                        'status': 'False',
                        'type': 'Ready'},
                       {'last_probe_time': None,
                        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 27, 16, 50, 1, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                        'message': None,
                        'reason': 'PodFailed',
                        'status': 'False',
                        'type': 'ContainersReady'},
                       {'last_probe_time': None,
                        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 27, 16, 8, 27, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                        'message': None,
                        'reason': None,
                        'status': 'True',
                        'type': 'PodScheduled'}]
```

The pod has a condition with reason set to EvictionByEvictionAPI and another with reason set to PodFailed. I suspect that the pod was evicted, leading to its failure, but I'm not entirely sure why.

1. What could be the reasons for a pod to be evicted via the Eviction API?
2. How can I prevent this from happening in the future or at least diagnose the root cause?

I can add more context if necessary